# How to convert html into doc without losing paragraphs?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I try to get text from a site. e.g. http://ahmetturanalkan.net/yazi/laik-cemaatin-kokleri-kadikoyde-mi/

It exports to word as a plain text. I mean without 
                                                                                                  < /p>< p> which makes it has no paragraphs. How do I convert it to text like on the original site with proper paragraphs?

this is the method that I get text

```
       private string yazial(string s)
    {
        string htmlContent = getsource(s);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
        var nodlar = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//article").InnerHtml;

        var nodlar1 = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//article/div[@class='page-header']").InnerText;
        //lectSingleNode
        docyap(nodlar,nodlar1);
        return nodlar;
    }
```

and this is the method which I try to export word doc

```
  private void docyap(string s,string g)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wBelge = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing);    

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph baslik = wBelge.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        object styleHeading = "Başlık 1";
        baslik.Range.set_Style(styleHeading);
        baslik.Range.Text = g; 

        baslik.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraf2;
        paragraf2 = wBelge.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        paragraf2.Range.Text = s;
        paragraf2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();           
        wBelge.SaveAs(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using like

```
           string yeni = nodlar.Replace("<p>", "    ").Replace("</p>","\n");
           yeni = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(yeni, "<div(.*)</div>", string.Format(""));
           yeni = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(yeni, "<div(.*)</a>", string.Format(""));
            yeni = Regex.Replace(yeni, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

but it is better to know neater solution if it exists